# Helm 'if' failing if key does not exist

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

This feels like such a simple problem.. but I can't seem to work out how to fix it..

I'm evaluating whether to create an ingress manifest, but need to evaluate whether ingress is enabled, but ignore if there is no ingress block.

```
{{- if index .Values (.Values.env) "ingress" "enabled" -}}
```

So this works when values has an ingress block. But if I create another environment in the values file it fails with nil pointer. I've tried various iterations of `hasKey` and some `and` & `or` combinations.

No ingress should be templated if either `.Values (.Values.env) "ingress" "enabled"` is equal to false OR if `.Values (.Values.env) "ingress"` does not exist.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Helm [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) and [`dict`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dict) functions to work around this.  At each level, instead of getting a Go `nil` value if the item doesn't exist, you can use `default` to make its value an empty list, which you can then step into.

```
{{- $env := index .Values .Values.env | default dict }}
{{- $ingress := $env.ingress | default dict }}
{{- if $ingress.enabled }}
...
{{- end }}
```

Syntactically, the bare word `dict` is equivalent to `(dict)` and parallel to `(dict "key" "value")` but with no arguments; it calls the `dict` function and returns an empty dictionary.  Then that's the argument to the `default` function.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to add a conditional judgment above, and no object is generated when there is no value.

According to the [helm document](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/), when the object is empty, the `if` statement judges to return `false`.

> A pipeline is evaluated as false if the value is:
>
> - a boolean false
> - a numeric zero
> - an empty string
> - a nil (empty or null)
> - an empty collection (map, slice, tuple, dict, array)

e.g.

values.yaml

```yaml
ingress:
  enable: false
```

templates/deployment.yaml

```yaml
{{- if .Values.ingress }}
{{- if .Values.ingress.enable }}
...
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: I tried that already, but it doesn't work because of the `.Values.env` addition, I have to use index or that fails.